# Efficiently getting i-th column of i-th 2D slice of 3D NumPy array, for all i

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing

Suppose I have a `NumPy` array `A` of shape `(N,N,N)`. From this, I form a `2D` array `B` of shape `(N,N)` as follows:

`B = np.column_stack( tuple(A[i,:,i] for i in range(N)) )`

In other words, for the `i-th` `2D` slice of `A`, I take it's `i-th` column; I then `stack` these columns to form `B`.

**My question is:**

Is there a more efficient way (`NumPy` indexing/slicing) to construct `B` from `A`; mainly, is it possible to eliminate the inner `for` loop over the `2D` slices of `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
idx = np.arange(N)  # or idx = range(N)
A[idx,:,idx].T
```

*Example*:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

idx = np.arange(3)
A[idx,:,idx].T
#array([[ 0, 10, 20],
#       [ 3, 13, 23],
#       [ 6, 16, 26]])

np.column_stack( tuple(A[i,:,i] for i in range(3)) )
#array([[ 0, 10, 20],
#       [ 3, 13, 23],
#       [ 6, 16, 26]])
```

*Timing*: it is faster for a large array

```
def adv_index(N):
    idx = range(N)
    return A[idx,:,idx].T

N = 100
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(N*N*N).reshape(N,N,N)
​    
%timeit np.column_stack(tuple(A[i,:,i] for i in range(N)))
# The slowest run took 4.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop

%timeit adv_index(N)
# The slowest run took 5.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 51.1 µs per loop

(np.column_stack(tuple(A[i,:,i] for i in range(N))) == adv_index(N)).all()
# True
```